# Django - How to filter products by price?

Tags: django, filter, price

I am trying to build an E-Commerce application using Django. I am trying to add a price filter using `select tag in HTML`. So, every time `select` `option` changes I want to change to filter product by low-to-high or vice-versa.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <label>
        <select class="bg-dark" name="price" id="priceFilter" onchange="getValue()">
            <option value="normal">Sort by Price</option>
            <option value="low">Low to High</option>
            <option value="high">High to Low</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```js
function getValue() {
    let option = document.getElementById('priceFilter');
    let value = option.value;

    let url = '/price_filter/';

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({'value': value})
    })

        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })

        .then((data) => {
            console.log('data:', data)
            location.reload()
        })
    }
```

**views.py**

```py
def filterByPrice(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    value = data['value']

    print(value)

    if value == 'low':
        products = Product.objects.all().order_by('productDiscountedPrice')
        context = {
            'products': products
        }
        return render(request, "Amazon/filteredResult.html", context)
    elif value == 'high':
        products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-productDiscountedPrice')
        context = {
            'products': products
        }
        return render(request, "Amazon/filteredResult.html", context)
    else:
        products = Product.objects.all()
        context = {
            'products': products
        }
        return render(request, "Amazon/filteredResult.html", context)
```

So, the problem is, It is not getting redirected to `filteredResult` page, but `value` in getting printed in `terminal`.

Any Idea why it is not getting redirected?

Comment: What do you mean by not getting redirected to filteredResult page? What is happening instead ? Also, since you are returning the same args, you should write a single return for more clarity.

Comment: @BriseBalloches It is not getting redirected anywhere. And about returning statement, I was trying to run the code that way.

Comment: In your fetch, you're trying to get response.json() when you are not actually returning any json, but html. The answer below is the right way, i just think you can't put a link in an option tag. You need to do it through onClick event.